# FileNotFound Exception When Trying To Read File Using getServletContext().getRealPath()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filepath, filenotfoundexception

My program is able to create and write to a file using the path-file:

```
private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "WebContent/Config/MyPublic.key";
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "WebContent/Config/MyPrivate.key";
```

And the correct files are generated within the folders according to the path declared above.

But then a **FileNotFoundException** error occurs when I try to read from those files using the path files:

```
private String REAL_PUBLIC_PATH = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/Config/MyPublic.key");
    private String REAL_PRIVATE_PATH = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/Config/MyPrivate.key");
```

This is the lines of code that is causing the error:

```
PublicKey pubKey = readPublicKeyFromFile(this.REAL_PUBLIC_PATH);
PrivateKey privKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile(this.REAL_PRIVATE_PATH);
```

Which is tied to the variables `REAL_PUBLIC_PATH` and `REAL_PUBLIC_PATH`.  Meaning there's something wrong with how the path file is being read.

My folder structure goes:

```
> MyProject
   >Web-Content
     >Config
        >MyPublic.key
        >MyPrivate.key
     >WEB-INF
     >META-INF
```

My full class code is below for context:

```
public class RSAEncryptionHelper extends HttpServlet {


    private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "WebContent/Config/MyPublic.key";
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "WebContent/Config/MyPrivate.key";

    private String REAL_PUBLIC_PATH = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/Config/MyPublic.key");
    private String REAL_PRIVATE_PATH = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/Config/MyPrivate.key");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("--GENERATE PUBLIC and PRIVATE KEY --");
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048); //1024 for normal securities
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            System.out.println("\n--PULLING OUT PARAMETERS WHICH MAKES KEYPAIR--\n");
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
            RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

            System.out.println("\n--SAVING PUBLIC KEY AND PRIVATE KEY TO FILES--\n");

            RSAEncryptionHelper rsaObj = new RSAEncryptionHelper();

            rsaObj.saveKeys(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE, rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPubKeySpec.getPublicExponent());
            rsaObj.saveKeys(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, rsaPrivKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPrivKeySpec.getPrivateExponent());

        }

        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void saveKeys(String fileName, BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Generating: " + fileName + "...");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
            oos.writeObject(mod);
            oos.writeObject(exp);
            System.out.println(fileName + "generated successfully");;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oos!=null)
            {
                oos.close();
                if (fos!= null)
                {
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public PublicKey readPublicKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        PublicKey publicKey = null;

        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();
            BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();

            //Get Public Key
            RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            publicKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
            return publicKey;
        }       
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeySpecException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (ois != null)
            {
                ois.close();
                if (fis != null)
                {
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return publicKey;
    }

    public PrivateKey readPrivateKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        PrivateKey privateKey = null;

        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();
            BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();

            //Get Public Key
            RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            privateKey = fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateKeySpec);
            return privateKey;
        }       
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeySpecException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (ois != null)
            {
                ois.close();
                if (fis != null)
                {
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return privateKey;
    }

    public byte[] encryptData(String data) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("\n--ENCRYPTION STARTED--");
        System.out.println("Data Before Encryption: " + data);
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedData = null;

        try
        {
            PublicKey pubKey = readPublicKeyFromFile(this.REAL_PUBLIC_PATH);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
            System.out.println("Encrypted Data: " + encryptedData);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (BadPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) 
        {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        System.out.println("--ENCRYPTION COMPLETED--");
        return encryptedData;
    }

    public String decryptData(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("\n--DECRYPTION STARTED--");
        byte[] decryptedData = null;

        String decData = "";

        try
        {
            PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile(this.REAL_PRIVATE_PATH);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);

            decData = new String(decryptedData);
            System.out.println("Decrypted Data: " + decData);


            return decData;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( IllegalBlockSizeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (BadPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        System.out.println("--DECRYPTION COMPLETED--");
        return decData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your keys already exist before you run the program?  if not, then getRealPath to a file that doesn't exist isn't going to work.

But that shouldn't matter because if you can access the files using private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE, why not use that same path to read the files.

So instead of this:

```
  PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile(this.REAL_PRIVATE_PATH);
```

Why not do this?

```
  PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile(this.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
```

If you've sucessfully written to a file using PRIVATE_KEY_FILE path, you can also read from the same path.